# Get host name from ipv6 address

Tags: c#, ipv6, net.tcp

I need to ascertain the calling computers host name within my wcf program. The following code only works if I supply an ipv4 address:

```
  System.Net.IPAddress[] addresses = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses("fe80::5423:9721:ff08:a07e");

  System.Net.IPHostEntry entry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(addresses[0]); //"192.168.0.107"); //fe80::5423:9721:ff08:a07e");
  string hostName = entry.HostName;
```

The calling computer is a Win8 RTM machine and only supplies the ipv6 address so the following code in my wcf program fails with a unknown host error:

```
OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint =
    prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
ipAddress = endpoint.Address;


System.Net.IPHostEntry entry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress(ipAddress);
hostName = entry.HostName;
aliases = entry.Aliases.ToList<string>();
```

The above code includes some attempted workarounds :-)

I've searched everywhere without any luck - any ideas?

Comment: Do you get a valid IPv6 host address? Given the valid IPv6 address of the computer (perhaps from the `ipconfig` command on that machine) can you look up the host name?

Comment: I get the valid ipv6 address but the GetHostByAddress fails unless you use an ipv4 address as the parameter.

Comment: That's pretty much my point. This has nothing to do with WCF, and instead has to do with getting a host name from an IPv6 address.

Comment: Does the computer you're running this on have IPv6 installed? See [Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143997.aspx) where it says IPv6 addresses may be filtered out.

Comment: Is there a reverse lookup entry for that IPv6 address? For example,  the reverse lookup entry for 2001:db8::567:89ab is b.a.9.8.7.6.5.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup).